# Access query for show occurred times in table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need a query for find how many times Item occurred in table. Can someone please help me on this query.[image: Expected outcome as below.]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your screen - instead either enter the data or use a screenshot. You have not indicated what you have tried, or what your output should be, but have you looked at a query that uses `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I apologies for this time @ Applecore

Answer (score 0):

On method in MS Access is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t as t2 where t2.fpid = t.fpid and t2.id <= t.id) as counter
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for support @ Gordon Linoff. Actually, I want to count the FP_Id (Country Name) in Count field.